# Loop two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a issue with two loops.

```
yellow=[
         {
          beta: {
               id: '25',
               name: 'tata'
           }
         }
        ]
home=[
       {
          house : [
          {
             title: 'alpha',
             name : 'Vik',
          },
          {
             title: 'alpha1',
             name : 'Vik1',
          },
        ]
      }]
```

I want this :

```
villa=[
        {
            beta:{ 
            id: 'toto', name: 'tata'
            },
          title: 'alpha',
          name : 'Vik'
        },
        {
            beta:{ 
            id: 'toto', name: 'tata'
            },
          title: 'alpha1',
          name : 'Vik1'
        }
      }
     ]
```

**Sorry I have edit the array**

I tried with a look with a loop with home.push(yellow) but the result is wrong.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Post your attempt, please.

Comment: also `home` have a syntax error

Comment: Yellow is an array. Try push just the object.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Can you please provide a clearer example and your attempt.

Comment: Question is unclear and poorly formatted. Please add a possible attempt you have tried.

Comment: Sorry I hope it's more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this

> Assume the yellow array has only 1 item

```
const yellow=[{beta: {id: '25', name: 'tata'}}];
const home=[{title: 'alpha', name : 'Vik'},
 {'alpha1', name : 'Vik1'} ];

// Assume the yellow array has only 1 item
const result = home.map((item)=>{
  return {...item,...yellow[0]}
});
```

> To Loop two array's and Assume the two arrays have the same length

```
const yellow=[{beta: {id: '25', name: 'tata'}}];
const home=[{title: 'alpha', name : 'Vik'},
 {'alpha1', name : 'Vik1'} ];

// Assume the yellow array has only 1 item
const result = home.map((item,index)=>{
  return {...item,...yellow[index]}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your `home` value was correct, like:

```
yellow = [{beta: {id: '25', name: 'tata'}}];
home = [{title: 'alpha', name : 'Vik'},{title: 'alpha1', name : 'Vik1'}];
```

Then I believe what you're looking for would look like this:

```js
home.reduce((res, h) => {
    yellow.forEach(y => {
        h.beta = y.beta;
        res.push(h)
    });
    return res;
}, []);
```